# How can I embed Google maps into a wxPython program?

Tags: python, google-maps, wxpython, gis

I would like to create a program using wxPython that uses Google maps to display and select geographic data.

Is there a proven, ready to use widget for this?

Comment: I don't know about wx, but if you use Qt (another GUI toolkit), you can embed webkit, then put any web content within that.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pre-made widgets that I'm aware of. I did find PySlip, which is similar to what you're talking about: http://code.google.com/p/pyslip/wiki/Introduction

There is a webkit port that's being worked on for wxPython as well. There's a preview build here that's kind of old:

http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/index.php?n=Main.Downloads

I know the author has been working on an update to it for quite some time though.